# DataBase Design for frequent delete operations

Tags: database-design, mysql, relational-database

We have a use case wherein we want to store incoming data and invalidate all the previously existing data pertaining to one parent entity.

ie Parent p1 --> has List< child> old_data ( already stored in the table )
now some new data comes in List new_data

**PS the table only has one index is the foreign key p1.ID**

EXAMPLE

EXISTING DATA

```
--------|-------------|-------

ID         Parent.ID     DATA

1.           P1.ID.       D1
2.           P1.ID.       D2
3.           P1.ID        D3
```

INCOMING DATA ( D4,D5,D6)

What we want

```
--------|-------------|-------

ID         Parent.ID        DATA

4.           P1.ID.       D4
5.           P1.ID.       D5
6.           P1.ID        D6
```

so we want to delete all the old_data present in the table first and then insert new_data

The major concern we see here is performance degradation wrt to frequent delete operation which will occur every time(frequency of incoming data associated with the parent is high)  new_data comes in. ( *we are not going through the setting of isValid  = 0 approach since it will bloat the table in no time* )
What's the best possible way to approach this. We are currently planning to use MariaDB.

Do we move to any other RDBMS or NoSQL DB  which gives better performance wrt deletes? or any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you identified an actual performance problem, or is this hypothetical?

Comment: hypothetical, we are in the design phase and looking at pros and cons of the approach

Comment: This seems to be relevant: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/big-deletes/

Comment: Will check this out . But the concern we see here is the frequency of delete and not the number of rows to be deleted? Do you have any other suggestions on the choice of database?

Comment: Presumably you picked MariaDB for other reasons.  Have you considered running some trials on MariaDB to see how it holds up?  It's hard to imagine taking more than about an hour to set something like that up.

Comment: And you're probably going to have to perform that exercise anyway, given the specific nature of your use case, regardless of the database you choose.

Comment: Thanks, the only reason we chose MariaDB is that our production database is MariaDB instance and this data will be primarily used for enterprise reporting

Comment: Well, OK.  But your choice to use MariaDB was already made for the production database, presumably for good reasons.  Those reasons still apply, and you can now add "we  have experience with it" to the list.  Note that MariaDB has [OLAP support.](https://siliconangle.com/2016/04/05/mariadb-adds-olap-support-to-transactional-database-engine/)

Comment: I don't see any reasons why performance *degradation* should happen here by repeated deletes. Do you have any real evidence (for example, by some performance measurements) that in a correctly indexed DB a straightforward DELETE/INSERT sequence will not fullfill your performance requirements?